# How to make multiple multiple tables in room during run time of an app?

Tags: android, android-room, data-persistence

I am trying to make a Ledger app in which there would one base table which would contain the name, phone number etc and a table containing all list of transaction corresponding to a particular person. Now I don't know how many persons I would add so tables need to be created during run time. But how should I do that?

I even tried a second where I would keep the **tranctionId** column as a foreign key in the base table and use it as a primary key in another table where all transaction would be stored in a **mutableListOf<>()** but it showing an error that use **type convertors**.

Please tell how should proceed or if there is some other way for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

> so tables need to be created during run time

Sorry, but Room does not support that directly. You can call [`getOpenHelper()` on your `RoomDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase?getOpenHelper()) and do that stuff manually if you want. A more conventional approach is to have one table for all persons, with a person's ID as being one column in that table.

Comment: There was an error  **use type converter **when I tried the second method( I mentioned it in the second portion of the question). What about that can that be solved anyway ?

Comment: @AshutoshPanda: Well, any manually-created tables will have to be consumed manually as well.